# How to import / print a bibliography created from a separate / external document?

Tags: biblatex, external-files

I have a document with a bibliography that I create using `biblatex` with the `biber` backend. I.e., somewhere in this document, there is a line

```
\printbibliography
```

which prints the bibliography (say what).

Now I am required to create an additional cover letter which repeats the bibliography. This is a different document (in a different directory if that matters) and I was wondering if there is a way to persuade `biblatex` to print the bibliography at the end of the cover letter again when I compile it. (That would, of course, require the original document to always be compiled first, but that I would manage.)

Any ideas?

(I could just copy over the pages with bibliography with `pdfpages` but that's ugly because that would have wrong page numbers and I would always have to adjust the page range, should it change in the original file.)

Answer (score 10):

There is no interface to import the exact bibliography of another document. But in certain situations work-arounds are available.

All the information for citations and the bibliography lives in the `.bbl` file. That file is written by Biber following requests by `biblatex` in the `.bcf` file. So you can try to import the `.bbl` file of the other document to obtain its bibliography. This works as long as the set-up in both documents is simple: You can't have multiple refsections, the importing document can't cite sources that were not cited in the original document, etc.

Assuming you have a document called `maindoc.tex` with citations and bibliography that has gone through the complete compilation sequence of LaTeX, Biber , LaTeX, LaTeX you can then import the bibliography from `maindoc` (it lives in `maindoc.bbl` so that file must exist) in another document (`coverletter.tex`) with

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\importbibfrom}[1]{%
  \def\blx@bblfile{%
    \blx@secinit
    \begingroup
    \blx@bblstart
    \InputIfFileExists{#1.bbl}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' found}%
       \global\toggletrue{blx@bbldone}%
       \blx@generate@bbl@mdfivesum@found{#1.bbl}}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' not found}%
       \typeout{No file #1.bbl.}%
       \blx@generate@bbl@mdfivesum@notfound}%
    \blx@bblend
    \endgroup
    % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
    \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}}

\let\blx@rerun@biber\relax
\makeatother

\importbibfrom{maindoc}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You only need to compile the importing document `coverletter` with LaTeX (at least twice), don't run Biber on that file.

You can cite all entries that are in the bibliography and get the exact same bibliography as `maindoc.tex`.

Assuming `maindoc.tex` was

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,vizedom:related}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the `coverletter.tex` from above yields

[image]

*edit:* See [How to use refsection and xcite together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473444/35864) for guidance on how to use different `refsection`s and for help with `defernumbers`.