# How to get same citation numbering in two standalone documents with same bibliography file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am preparing submission for a journal which asked me to submit tables as separate pdf file. I compiled table as a standalone document with same bibliography file as the main paper. Most citation e.g. `\cite{foo}` and `\cite{bar}` were replaced by different numbers in table pdf which are different than the numbers in main paper. This is expected but this is not what I need. I want the citation numbering in table pdf to match the main reference in paper. Currently I have the following ad-hoc solution:

- Compile the table along with the main paper but with `\pagebreak` and remove the table page from paper and save it separately.

This is not to my liking. Is there any way I can enforce the same numbering of citation in two different documents compiled separately?

I am using `biblatex` with lualatex.

**MWE:**

file `table.bbl` copied from bbl file generated after compiling another document.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{hebb_organization_2005}
Hebb DO (2005) {\em The {Organization} of {Behavior}: {A} {Neuropsychological}
  {Theory}}.
\newblock (Psychology Press).
\newblock Google-Books-ID: uyV5AgAAQBAJ.

\bibitem{takeuchi_synaptic_2014}
Takeuchi T, Duszkiewicz AJ, Morris RGM (2014) The synaptic plasticity and
  memory hypothesis: encoding, storage and persistence.
\newblock {\em Phil. Trans. R. Soc. B} 369(1633):20130288.
\newblock 00078.

\end{thebibliography}
```

`table.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand\SEB[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\def\RC{\rowcolor{gray!10}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[ ]{biblatex}

% This trick is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426982/8087
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\importbibfrom}[1]{%
  \def\blx@bblfile{%
    \blx@secinit
    \begingroup
    \blx@bblstart
    \InputIfFileExists{#1.bbl}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' found}%
       \global\toggletrue{blx@bbldone}}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' not found}%
       \typeout{No file #1.bbl.}}%
    \blx@bblend
    \endgroup
    % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
    \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}}
\global\let\blx@rerun@biber\relax
\makeatother

\importbibfrom{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llp{0.1\linewidth}p{.15\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Ref/Notes}\\
    \midrule
    A & B & C & \cite{hebb_organization_2005}\cite{takeuchi_synaptic_2014}
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In general it is hard to access the citations of a different document, but it is possible in certain cases, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864

Comment: If the ordering of citation is defined by the main text, you could copy the main.bbl to table.bbl and not run biber on table. I'm not sure this works with biblatex, but is efficient with old fashion bibtex route. An elaborate version of this procedure is given in the post refered to in the previous comment.

Comment: Any news here? Did the link help? If not, what would you like to change?

Comment: @moewe I haven't tried the solution yet. I'll update you as soon as I try it this weekend.

Comment: @moewe I could not get citation to appear. It turns out the `pnas-new` style uses natbib and bib files generated can not be used with biblatex. I am trying with different backend. I'll update if something changes.

Comment: `.bib` files for use with `natbib` can certainly be used with `biblatex` as well. You just have to run Biber. But if you are not using `biblatex` at all, you may want to remove the reference to `biblatex` in the body of your question and the tag.

Comment: @moewe Surely I am missing something. I've added the MWE. Thanks for all the effort.

Comment: Ah now I understand. The **`.bbl`** file is produced by `natbib`. In that case the answer is sadly: No, you can't import that file for use with `biblatex`. The `.bbl`s that `biblatex` needs and produces are strictly and completely incompatible with those from BibTeX.

Comment: @moewe sigh :-( . Anyway thanks a lot. It might be useful somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both documents, the one you want to import the bibliography from and the one you import to, use the same bibliography set-up, it is possible to cook something up that works in certain cases. See [How to import / print a bibliography created from a separate / external document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864)

Your problem is that you have a `.bbl` file created by `pnas-new.bst`  and want to import that into a document that uses `biblatex`. That does not work since `biblatex`'s `.bbl` files and the `.bbl` files produced by BibTeX's `.bst` styles are completely incompatible and not mutually understandable.

The solution in this case is to not load `biblatex` in `table.tex`

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\newcommand\SEB[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\def\RC{\rowcolor{gray!10}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llp{0.1\linewidth}p{.15\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Ref/Notes}\\
    \midrule
    A & B & C & \cite{hebb_organization_2005}\cite{takeuchi_synaptic_2014}\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\input{table.bbl}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

if compiled in the same folder as `table.bbl` from the question.

You can't really use most of `biblatex`'s advanced features anyway if you import the `.bbl` from elsewhere, so you can just go with `natbib` here.